# Can't load a .cls file in TexStudio -Texlive 2018

Tags: texlive, texstudio, document-classes, texlive-2018

I'm working in Windows 10 using TexStudio on TexLive 2018 distro.
I'm writing my bachelor final thesis and I need to use a document class defined by my academic department. I have a .cls file named "Tptesi2.cls" and my  .tex file starts with `\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{Tptesi2}`.
The problem is that when I bring the mouse pointer on "Tptesi2", TexStudio show a little box that says

> Class: Tptesi2 (non trovato)

that in italian means "class not found". The document is compiled with a warning

> destination with the same identifier (name{page.i}) has been already used, duplicate ignored \relax l.91 \cleardoublepage [1

and it looks ok, but unfortunately I can't be sure of it because I don't have a thesis sample with this document class. 
I gave a look to the folder `C:\texlive\2018\tex\latex` and I found many folders containing .cls files corresponding to document classes that are recognized by TexStudio, so I create a folder with the same "Tptesi2" and I put the file in it.
But this approach didn't work, so I tried to follow the steps described in [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te) but also in this way I didn't solved the problem.
I'm missing some configuration on TexStudio or I put the file in the wrong folder, or both?

#### EDIT

TexStudio continues to show the same message, but I noticed that right clicking on the class name, left clicking on "show documentantion" the docs are showed correcly.

Comment: You can safely ignore this message from texstudio. If latex would not find the documentclass you would get a ton of error messages in the .log file and no sensible output. Actually I get this toltip for every documentclass, even for the standard latex classes.

Comment: About the warning you get: this looks as if the same name is used for multiples labels. You should check this to make sure all the cross references go to the correct location.

Comment: It would be better to place your .cls file not in `C:\texlive\2018\tex\latex `, otherwise it might be removed when you upgrade your tex distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the replies  @samcarter. About the multiple labels, I should check if a package is loaded both in the.cls file and my .tex file,right?

Comment: The warning is not about packages. Check in your document if you use two `\label` with the same name, e.g. two times `\lable{foo}`

Comment: If you cannot find the source of the warning, you could try to trim your document down to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that still produces the warning and we can probably help you.

Comment: Maybe there's something like `\setcounter{page}{1}` that resets page number back to 1 in your document. That's usually the case when such warnings show up.  (for example, if you had wanted the cover page to be page `i`, but also your first chapter to be on page `1`.)

Comment: @Troy  exactly, intoduction pages are counted using roman numbers, instead in all other chapters pages are numbered using arabic numbers. Can I ignore this warning or should I fix it? And how?

Comment: @HJuls2 You can ignore it. But if it really bothers you, pass `pageanchor=false` when loading the `hyperref` package in your preamble. Or if `hyperref` is loaded inside `Tptesi2.cls`, you may try `PassOptionsToPackage{pageanchor=false}{hyperref}` before `\documentclass{Tptesi2}` in your `.tex` file.

Comment: @Troy Thank you very much, for now I'm going to accept your first advice ignoring the warning, because I have only a little experience with Latex, I'll consider to fix in a later time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments.